# protocol.http.Response405WithoutAllowHeader in restsharp

Tags: api, xamarin, blazor, maui, restsharp

I have used Restsharp in order to get details from an API and currently I am working on a blazor hybrid project. I can get the request from the API in  the windows app but when I am going to use the android app for this it is failing and unable to get the response. I have put my API calling part over here.

```
var client = new RestClient(tokenInfo.BaseURL);                 
var request = new RestRequest(endpointInfo.EndPointURL, Method.Get);   
request.AddHeader("X-API-KEY","");                
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");                 
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

when I am going to get the response it gets failed.

[image]

i tried to find a solution using fault response but it didnt work.pls help me to solve this problm,appriciate all of your help.

Comment: What do the API docs say?  What conditions cause a 405?

Comment: it says the method(GET,POST,..) is not allowed

Comment: i found this article 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276728/405-status-code-not-returning-the-response-properly
but i don't how to apply this thing with my code